# TokenMismatch Error on Ajax Requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting `TokenMismatch` Error on Ajax Submit when I submit form it gives me error. Here I am using `Laravel 5.2`. Where I am passing `X-CSRF-TOKEN` on ajax call. Set Token on on meta on `default.blade.php`. I've tried all possible solutions from `StackOverflow`.

1. Changing permission of storage folder.
2. Tried clearing cache.
3. Try adding `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {`
4. Adding `token` to header of ajax function.
5. Tried adding `token` field inside form.

Can anyone find any solution from below code.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Below is my Category HTML Form `category.blade.php`:

```
<form method="POST" name="category-add-form" id="category-add-form" action="{{route("category-add")}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Category Title:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="category_title" type="text" value="" id="category_title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Description:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="category_description" cols="50" rows="10" id="category_description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Add CAtegory">
    </div>
</form>
```

Below id my `app.js`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Below is my `category-add.js` here is my ajax code. I've not included whole function.

```
var request;
var $inputs = $("#category-add").find("input, select, button, textarea");
var formData = new FormData($("#category-add")[0]);
request = $.ajax({
    url: $("#category-add").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //Notification.init(response.message);
    //App.unblockUI('.block-panel-box');
});
request.error(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //App.unblockUI('.block-panel-box');
});
request.always(function () {
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Below is my `default.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Project</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/font-awesome.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/simple-line-icons.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/bootstrap.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/components-md.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/plugins-md.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/layout.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/blue.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
        <link href="{{asset("public/css/responsive.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-container-bg-solid page-sidebar-closed page-md">
        @include('user.layout.header')
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        <div class="page-container">
            @include('user.layout.sidebar')
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
        @include('user.layout.footer')
        <div class="quick-nav-overlay"></div>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/jquery.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/bootstrap.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/app.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset("public/js/category-add.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my category route file `route.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
    Route::post('/category-add', array("as" => "category-add","uses" => "CategoryController@store"));
});
```

Below is my `CategoryController.php`

```
class CategoryController extends Controller {
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $category = Category::create($inputs);
        if($category){
            $responseArray = array("status"=>true,"message"=>"Category successfully created");
        } else {
            $responseArray = array("status"=>false,"message"=>"Could not add category please try again later");
        }
        return response()->json($responseArray);
    }
}
```

Below is my `.env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:ratSluNv930gb3wp1UOabW6Ze3jEJn3ixtTX/wgqYZc=
APP_URL=http://project.dev/ts/cart-products

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cart-products
DB_USERNAME=hellocart
DB_PASSWORD=j@yshre33r@m

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Below is my `config/session.php` file

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'cart-products',
    'path' => '/ts/cart-products', //Change path variable URL form '/cart-products' to '/ts/cart-products'
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

Below is my `Kernal.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Try by removing headers from your Ajax request.category-add.js and make sure app.js is already included before category-add.js. As you have already mentioned in ajaxSetUp it is global no need to mentioned it again.

Comment: `app.js` is already included before the `category-add.js`. And I also tried by removing headers from one by one `app.js` and `category-add.js`, but no luck

Comment: Check Network Tab in chrome. Check request headers if theres `_token`

Comment: @aldrin27 : Yes, I tried displaying from console and token was there

Comment: Have you checked all codes given in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you haven't properly set the Session Cookie Path in config/session.php to sub subdirectory as you project is not in root of your domain.

So if your APP_URL is **http://project.dev/ts/cart-products**

then your path in config/session.php should be as follow

```
'path' => '/ts/cart-products'
```

you forgot to add '/ts'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inject '_token' in data will be sent. Like that

```
data : {
'_token' : "{{ csrf_token() }}",
'data'   : formData
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately not working, token is there on console.

Comment: because you put csrf_token() function in js file, you have to create a new variable named token on blade and inject it into js file

Comment: will `FormData` not get value from the Form?

Comment: No, on blade you just add <script>var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";</script>
And in js file you put _token variable in data.
data : {
'_token' : _token,
'data'   : formData
}
This will work for you

Comment: As I already mention that ajax function in written in `category-add.js` file, so there I can not write your code there. As I told you that displaying token value on *console*

Comment: is there any other solution? Did not found any issue in given code?

Comment: I met the same issue before, header did not work and Only add _token variable in data you send with ajax

Comment: Don't by pass token verifying, It may cause security troubles

Comment: I am getting both the token from header and in the post

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the "helpers" entry in category-add.js, then copy the "ajaxSetup" in the same file, bevor send the ajax request.

Comment: where is `helpers` in `category-add.js`?

Comment: Sorry, not "helpers" i mean "headers"

Comment: You mean remove headers from ajax and copy `ajaxSetup()`  and paste it to ajax function?

Comment: is there any other solution? Did not found any issue in given code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="quick-nav-overlay"></div>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/jquery.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/bootstrap.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
</script>
        <script src="{{asset("public/js/app.min.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset("public/js/category-add.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As you can see I added var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}"; before your js files, so you can reuse this variable in any js file that implement into this blade, and in ajax you just do like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: $("#category-add").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        '_token' : _token,
        'data'   : formData
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: oh, you just replace _token by your token,

Comment: I have `_token` inside the form and that is getting using jquery `Formdata`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step

project folder/app/http/kernal.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      //  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

put this line in comment

> \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

Comment: Can you please explain why it is required to comment?

Comment: \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class is middleware. checking csrf token in every request.

Comment: is there any other solution? Did not found any issue in given code?

Answer (score 0):

you can set  `X-CSRF-TOKEN` like that. see for more detail [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) official site

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

     $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

Comment: is there any other solution? Did not found any issue in given code?