# Laravel TokenMismatchException caused in routes/web.php

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I am learning `Routing` in `Laravel 5.4` by viewing a tutorial created by `DevDojo`. Using the following codes in `routes/web.php` will emerge the `TokenMismatchException` error and my code does not work after I press the submit button:

```
Route::post('test', function () {
    return 'Printed by the route responsible for test post action.';
});

Route::get('test', function () {
    echo '<form method="post" action="test">';
    echo '<input type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
});
```

I searched this same forum here and also the other places on the net like `laravel.io` or `laracasts.com` and everyone is talking about problems that occur when Laravel tries to detect the `session` of the request that is getting made.  
I tried to fix the problem by adding the following lines to the `Route::get` rules but the issue does not get fixed:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_field();">';
```

I hope you help me fix it by telling me how to properly use `csrf_field()`, `csrf_token()` or anything else needed here in the route file. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: csrf token will be not work by adding as string. Try this  `value="'.csrf_token().'"`

Comment: what happens if you try this echo '<form method="post" action="test">{{ csrf_field() }}<input type="submit"></form>';

Comment: [Check Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44721142/7894379) for token mismatch solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csrf_token()` just gives you the token.

`csrf_field()` builds the entire input field for you.

example:

`{{ csrf_token() }}`  // Outputs: SomeRandomString

`{{ csrf_field() }}`  // Outputs: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="SomeRandomString">`

in your question:
use

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_token();">;
```

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_field();">;
```

on the other hand

you could use

```
echo csrf_field();
```

OR

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Dear friend, as you mentioned I should have paid noticed to the usage of each function. I changed my code and added the `echo csrf_field;` right before ending the form and it is now working awesome. Thank you again. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with the hidden inputs (if you've got a fresh Laravel install, otherwise make sure checking the token isn't disabled);

I recommend you use the (official) Form Builder for Laravel to handle forms ([have a look here](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html)).

Afterwards, have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form):

(1)

`{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'profile')) }}`
 your form stuff goes here

`{{ Form::close() }}`

(2) Make sure to have this to output the token: `echo Form::token();` (before you close the form)

(3) And finally, have a POST Route registered, that checks the token:

`Route::post('profile', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{
    //
}));`

Alternatively, you can specify form action directly to the function (my personal favorite):

`echo Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method'))`

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for the awesome links you provided. It will surly help me work better with this framework.